# Calling a web api method with custom object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, http-get

Usually I send my post request with a custom parameter and a custom return and object using

```
HttpClientExtension.PostAsJsonAsync<T>
```

This allows my to call a post method with a custom object.

Now, I want to be able to send my custom object as a parameter and return value to a GET Method.
Lets say my method signature is

```
[HttpGet]
public MyMethodResponse MyMethod(MyMethodRequest request)
```

How can I send a request when I have an instance of MyMethodRequest ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode `MyMethodRequest` onto the query string. You can either encode it as separate query string parameters or as a single one. You have handle the encoding yourself on the client side, remembering to URI-encode the parameters. Decoding is done using a custom ModelBinder or TypeConverter respectively. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/20/how-to-bind-to-custom-objects-in-action-signatures-in-mvc-webapi.aspx) shows examples of binding a complex object on the query string.